Interaction term negative when both its components are positive?
I examined the effect of labour cost, labour quality and their interaction (cost*quality) on FDI, but I got positive coff. of both components and negative coff. of interaction term. How could to interpret this result in this situation?

Welcome to the site! Could you please give a bit more detail about your data and perhaps the actual results?

The positive coefficient for labor cost suggests that, holding labor quality constant, an increase in labor cost is associated with an increase in Foreign Direct Investment (FDI). A similar interpretation can be made with labor quality.
Finally, the negative coefficient for the interaction Term (Labor Cost * Labor Quality) suggests that the combined effect of labor cost and labor quality on FDI is less than the sum of their individual effects. In other words, as both labor cost and labor quality increase together, their positive impact on FDI diminishes.
